# Parsing string with special character and returning the output

Tags: javascript

I know its a pretty simple question, but to anyone who is new to Javascript this can be interesting.

Is there any fastest way to parse this string and get the color for the fruit like shown below :

```
var fruitAndColors = "APPLE=RED&GUAVA=GREEN&STRAWBERRY=RED&BANANA=yellow&ORANGE=orange"
var applecolor = getColor("APPLE") // RED
var bananaColor = getColor("BANANA") //yellow
```

Comment: While I am not an expert in javascript enough to tell you the "fastest way", I can see regex being pretty quick, possibly the fastest way. A method that's probably slower but works is splitting the string and converting it into an object perhaps.

Comment: Whatever solution you are choosing it will unlikely be the bottleneck in your application. Should the string represent URL query parameters? Is the code running in the browser? If yes you could just use [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/URLSearchParams).

Comment: Why don't we just make a map out of that string instead of using a regex to lookup key value pair every time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) passing in the fruit, and returning the first [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).

```js
const fruitAndColors = 'APPLE=RED&GUAVA=GREEN&STRAWBERRY=RED&BANANA=yellow&ORANGE=orange';

console.log(getColor('APPLE', fruitAndColors));
console.log(getColor('GUAVA', fruitAndColors));
console.log(getColor('STRAWBERRY', fruitAndColors));
console.log(getColor('BANANA', fruitAndColors));
console.log(getColor('ORANGE', fruitAndColors));

function getColor(fruit, fruitAndColors) {
  const regex = new RegExp(`${fruit}=([A-Za-z]+)`);
  return fruitAndColors.match(regex)[1];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a regex `match` approach:

```js
function getColor(fruitAndColors, fruit) {
    return fruitAndColors.match(new RegExp("\\b" + fruit + "=([^&]+)"))[1];
}

var fruitAndColors = "APPLE=RED&GUAVA=GREEN&STRAWBERRY=RED&BANANA=yellow&ORANGE=orange"
console.log(getColor(fruitAndColors, "APPLE"));  // RED
console.log(getColor(fruitAndColors, "BANANA")); //yellow
```

For the case of searching for `APPLE` we use the following regex pattern:

```regex
\bAPPLE=([^&]+)
```

This places the key (the color) in the first capture group, which the helper function then returns.

Answer (score 3):

Regex will probably be the best bet for this however it is definitely not my strong-suit. That said, here's what I came up with just some Javascript:

```
var fruitAndColors =
  'APPLE=RED&GUAVA=GREEN&STRAWBERRY=RED&BANANA=yellow&ORANGE=orange';

const getColor = (key) => {
  const entries = fruitAndColors.split('&').reduce((acc, val) => {
    const [fruit, color] = val.split('=');
    acc[fruit] = color;
    return acc;
  }, {});

  return entries[key];
};

var appleColor = getColor('APPLE'); // RED
var bananaColor = getColor('BANANA'); //yellow
```

Answer (score 3):

A little class that handle that kind of url parse

```js
class UrlParse {
    #objects;
  
  constructor(uri) {
    this.uri = uri
    this.objects = {}
    this.parse()
  }
  
  parse() {
    let arr = this.uri.split('&')
    
    for (let a of arr) {
        let arr = a.split(/\=/)
        this.objects[arr[0]] = arr[1]
    }
  }
  
  getName(name) {
    return this.objects[name]
  }
}
var fruitAndColors = "APPLE=RED&GUAVA=GREEN&STRAWBERRY=RED&BANANA=yellow&ORANGE=orange"

let p = new UrlParse(fruitAndColors)
console.log(p.getName('BANANA'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't we just use a map instead of parsing it with regex. I think that would be more efficient.

```js
const str = "APPLE=RED&GUAVA=GREEN&STRAWBERRY=RED&BANANA=yellow&ORANGE=orange";

const fruitColorArray = str.split("&").map((value) => value.split("="));
const fruitColorMap = new Map(fruitColorArray);

function getColor(fruit) {
  return fruitColorMap.get(fruit);
}

const applecolor = getColor("APPLE"); // RED
const bananaColor = getColor("BANANA"); //yellow

console.log(applecolor, bananaColor);
```